# Unexpected token import - jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jsfiddle

I am trying to make the toastr library work in jsfiddle but I keep getting this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

This is my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/77255/

This is my code:

```
import VueToastr from '@deveodk/vue-toastr';
Vue.use(VueToastr, {
    defaultPosition: 'toast-bottom-left',
    defaultType: 'info',
    defaultTimeout: 1000
});
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {    
  },
  created(){
    this.$toastr('success', 'it works!', 'Yeahh');
  },
  methods: {          
  }
})
```

and this is the library reference: https://github.com/Deveodk/vue-toastr

Does import keyword not work in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imports does not work on JSFIDDLE. You need to install the package and refer using import, which is not supported. Instead you can do this,

You can refer the library using external url,

```
https://unpkg.com/vue-toastr-2@0.0.8/dist/vue-toastr-2.js
https://unpkg.com/vue-toastr-2/dist/vue-toastr-2.min.css
```

**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/75154x8w/)**

Comment: Thanks it worked. Could you explain why did you change my line `this.$toastr('success', 'it works!', 'Yeahh');` to a success method? `this.$toastr.success('Message', 'Title');` and why does my code not work of `this.$toastr('success', 'it works!', 'Yeahh');`

Comment: Read the documentation here https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-toastr-2. and the aprameters

Comment: But here https://github.com/Deveodk/vue-toastr this code is given `this.$toastr('success', 'it works!', 'Yeahh')` would it only work when import is enabled?

Comment: not sure about that, probably you can refer to the earlier version and see

Comment: cool. No problems. Thank you. I posted one more question if you have time ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47362579/how-do-i-handle-click-event-on-the-button-inside-toastr