# How do I handle click event on the button inside toastr?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to handle the button click event inside the toastr. I am using this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-toastr-2

This is my code:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'vue-toastr-2'
  },
  created: function() {
    this.$toastr.success('Click here to fire an event <button @click="clickMe">Hello</button>', 'Title');
  },
  methods: {
    clickMe() {
      alert('Clicked');
      // write some more code 
    }
  }
})
```

Basically I want that when `clickMe` is clicked, my function inside the component should get called. How would I do this?

This is my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/75154x8w/2/

Comment: i guess this is not achievable undless you design a custom component, usually toast messages are without buttons. in this case you need a modal windo

Comment: Is this button for closing toast ? .. if yes this is supported out of the box .. if no I don't think this will be possible using this component unless the whole toast is clickable instead of just the button

Answer (score 1):

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'vue-toastr-2'
  },
  created: function() {
    this.$toastr.success('Click here to fire an event <button onclick="app.clickMe()">Hello</button>', 'Title');
  },
  methods: {
    clickMe() {
      alert('Clicked');
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: @WaldemarIce Did you test it? I don't see it working?